# Mongoose, MongoDb, Node. Mongoose object not registering find()

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

When i'm getting to my routes and requesting to getUSers from my mongoDB it says the User.find() is not defined. Sorry in advance if i use incorrect terminology i'm jumping in face first.

I'm assuming my routing is done incorrectly somewhere or i didn't include one file somewhere I'm hoping ya'll can help me determine if i'm either storing a file incorrectly in my structure, calling a file at the wrong time, or not initializing a variable correctly? Thanks for the help in advance.

Do i need an additional plugin to read and write to the database?

I keep getting the the following error it says usercontroller.js:20

```
Error: <!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title></title><link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/style.css"></head><body><h1>undefined is not a function</h1><h2></h2><pre>TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at getUsers (c:\Users\Ravenous\kitchen\routes\user_api.js:5:10)
    at c:\Users\Ravenous\kitchen\routes\user_api.js:26:3
```

file structure in case it helps

```
-bin
-node_modules-\
    -user-app-\
        -user.js           //this is the model written with mongoose schema
-public-\
    -html
    -images
    -javascripts-\
        -userController
        -userService       //AngularJS factory
    -stylesheets
    -index.html
-routes-\
    -user_api.js           //with other useful routes inside.
-views                     //has some jade view engines that came with express-generator
-app.js
-package.JSON
```

I have this for the user model -- file:  node_modules/user-app/user.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var UserSchema = new Schema({
    user_name: String,
    password: String,
    email: String,
    location: String,
    date_created : {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});

var User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

module.exports= {User:User};
```

I then import user.js file to the ./routes/user_api.js file which looks like this

user_api.js :

```
var User = require('./node_modules/user-app/user');


function getUsers(res){
        User.find().populate('users').exec(function(err, users){

            // if there is an error retrieving, send the error. nothing after res.send(err) will execute
            if (err){
                res.send(err)
            }else{
                console.log(users[0][0].name)
                res.json(users); // return all users in JSON format 
                db.close();
            }       
        })
};


module.exports = function(app) {

    // api -----------------------------------------------------------
    // get all users
    app.get('/node_modules/user-app/user', function(req, res) {

        // use mongoose to get all users in the database
        getUsers(res);
    });

    // create user and send back all users after creation
    app.post('/node_modules/user-app/user', function(req, res) {

        // create a user, information comes from AJAX request from Angular
        User.create({
            user_name: User.user_name,
            password: User.password,
            email: User.email,
            location: User.location,
            done : false
        }, function(err, todo) {
            if (err){
                res.send(err);
            }else{
                // get and return all the users after creating one
                getUsers(res);
            }
        });

    });

    // delete a user
    app.delete('/node_modules/user-app/user:user_id', function(req, res) {
        User.remove({
            _id : req.params.user_id
        }, function(err, user) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);

            getUsers(res);
        });
    });
};
```

I'm adding this user_api route and get method to the app.js file like so

```
// loading some required modules above this

var app = express();

var user = require('./routes/user_api')(app);
```

to handle the Angular and Node connection and state sharing i'm using the following

userController.js:

```
(function(){
'use strict'
var userCtrl = angular.module("userController",[]);
console.log('userController init')

userCtrl.controller('UserController', ['$scope','$http','Users',function($scope,$http,Users){
    $scope.users = {};
    $scope.loading = true;


console.log ("user init");
    Users.get()
        .success(function(data){
            $scope.users = data;
            $scope.loading = false;
            console.log(data)
        })

        .error(function(err){
            console.log('Error: ' + err);
        });
    $scope.createUser = function(){
        if($scope.users.user_name != false){
            console.log($scope.users.user_name)
            $scope.loading = true;

            Users.create($scope.users)

                .success(function(data){
                    $scope.loading=false;
                    $scope.users = data;
                    console.log(data);
                })
                .error(function(err){
                    console.log('Error: ' + err);
                });
        }
    };
}]);

})();
```

Comment: Remove `User.save(function()..)` from your getUsers() function. Why do you have it in the first place?

Comment: It was there to save the user to the database and then retrieve all the users, long day of failing is why that ended up in there. 

Thanks for getting back to me so quickly I updated the file but i'm still getting the same error.

Comment: @BidhanA I currenctly have mongose.connect(URL) set in my server file should it be some where else or possibly connecting everytime i ask to get data? I feel like this might be causing the problem if mongoose can't use the find() function... thoughts?

Comment: I think you haven't required your user model properly. Inside your user model, try doing this instead `module.exports= User;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the line where you require User to

```
var User = require('./node_modules/user-app/user').User;
```

This is because in your export statement when you define a user you have the line:

```
module.exports = {User:User};
```

So, you are exporting an object that has a User property on it.

Comment: I think this has solved my problem, but i don't know yet because now i'm getting error: null.

 I will dig deeper thx for getting me past that one!

Comment: Thanks that solved the problem. What is mongoose doing when that is included at the end and whats happening without it? 

now to find out how to use this get data to populate the page... X0

Comment: If your export statement was `module.exports = {User: 5}`, then `console.log(require('./node_modules/user-app/user'))` would print "{User:5}" and `console.log(require('./node_modules/user-app/user').User)` would print "5"